# Why does a middle click in Mate Terminal create files in my home folder?

Tags: command-line, mate

While scrolling through and reading the `man rsync` page in Mate Terminal 1.24.1 (Ubuntu Mate 20.10) I did a middle click in the window and it created a file in my home folder named after some short random excerpt of the man page, and its contents is some bizarre 5000 line combination of the rsync man page and the `man` pager's help text.

I repeated it and new files were created with varying length of a few hundred lines.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default on MATE Desktop middle mouse button can be used for pasting text (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in apps or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in terminal). In some apps like `man` it may cause strange behavior as you have just seen.

You can switch this feature off if you visit MATE Control Center → Mouse Preferences (or `mate-mouse-properties`) and then in **General** section uncheck **Enable middlemouse paste**.
Or programmatically:

```
gsettings set org.mate.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste false
```

to revert use

```
gsettings set org.mate.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste true
```